# How to display the value corresponding to a particular div among multiple divs in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have many div containing the same class and contents. When I am clicking a particular div, I want to display a particular value in that div only.When i am clicking the next div , I want to display another value(inside the span tag).

```
<div class="ann">

       <p>Hello</p>
       <span></span>

</div>
<div class="ann">

       <p>Hello</p>
       <span></span>

</div>
```

I want to display the corresponding value in the corresponding div.But currently the value is displaying in all the divs. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Please add all pertinent code

Answer (score 1):

You can easily using this in javascript.

```
<div class="ann" onclick="show(this);">

       <p>First Div</p>
       <span></span>

</div>
<div class="ann" onclick="show(this);">

       <p>Second Div</p>
       <span></span>

</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var count=0;
function show(id){
        count++;
        $(id).find('span').html("Random Text"+count);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pxoexxmq/

If this is not what you are looking for then kindly explain the problem in details.